# Use history search with a space?

Tags: bash, command-history

If I want to run the last instance of `foo`, I can do:

```
!foo
```

What if I want to use the last instance of sub command `foo bar`? Using:

```
!foo bar
```

Will result in using the last `foo` command and appending `bar`.

I also tried with quotes but that didn't work. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: `!?bar` might do for you if `bar` is sufficiently unique.  You can also use `^Rfoo bar`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti thanks, `^R` should work for what I need